# How to stop clang-format break fields seperator(::)?

Tags: clang-format

clang-format version 15.0.6

**Question**> Which settings I can use to get the expected format shown below?

Thank you

What I see:

```
auto amount =
    msg[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA::
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]
        .get<double>();
```

What I expect:

```
auto amount =
    msg[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA::bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]
        .get<double>();
```

My current settings for Break:

```
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't set the option `ColumnLimit`. By default, it is set to `80`. Try setting that manually, or if you don't want it to wrap, then set it to `0`.

Without setting ColumnLimit:

```
auto amount =
    msg[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA::
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]
        .get<double>();
```

After setting `ColumnLimit: 0`:

```
auto amount =
    msg[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA::bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]
        .get<double>();
```

Comment: I have used ColumnLimit: 80. By setting ColumnLimit: 0 will NOT work my case since it will stop splitting long line into smaller segments.

Comment: Then why not increase columnlength ? 90 or 100 maybe?

Comment: Any hard-code ColumLimit will have issues later. I was looking for a rule that enforces the non-breakable token for ::